# get Total of dateTime

Tags: python, datetime

How can I calculate the datetime for these strings:

1. `offline_dt  = "Jan 31 23:01:43"`
2. `offline_dt  = "Feb  1 01:19:01"` (there are 2 spaces between `Feb`
   and `1`)

I tried this code, however I only the first one worked:

```
offline_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(offline,"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce... both examples worked as expected for me (python 2.7.9 and 3.4.3).

Comment: `datetime.strptime("Feb  1 01:19:01", "%b %d %H:%M:%S")` works as is (there are two spaces in the code between `Feb` and `1` but the comment displays it as one). What is your environment (OS, Python version)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert double spaces into a single space before processing.

```
offline.replace("  ", " ")
```

Comment: Simple and effective answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might also have to do with the fact that `%d` expects a zero-padded number- 01 and not 1.

Other than that, you can use regex to consolidate whitespace as such:

```
import re
offline = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', offline)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
d ='Feb  1 01:19:01'
p = re.compile(r"\s{2}(?=\d\D)")
p.sub(" 0",d)
'Feb 01 01:19:01'
```

Find 2 white spaces followed by a single digit, which is followed by a non digit and insert 0 (Zero) before the digit.